# Qt - make selection background have similar background to item

Tags: css, pyqt

How can I make the background for when an item is selected to be some sort of blend of current cell background?

The default item-selection background is blue and say if my cell is red, then I'd want it to be red with slightly less opacity:

[Example image of how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epKn2.png)

[Example image of how I'd like it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMPwz.png)

I have tried setting the color to be transparent:

```
setStyleSheet("selection-background-color: transparent")
```

And also the rgba feature with opacity 1%:

```
setStyleSheet("selection-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)")
```

But neither retain the original color

Answer (score 1):

This example will give you some insight how to manage with tablewidgets and item

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

data = {'col1':['red','blue','green']}

class MyTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, *args):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.data = data
        self.setmydata()
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.setStyleSheet("""QTableView::item:focus
            {
                selection-background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 128);
            }""")


    def setmydata(self):
        horHeaders = []
        for n, key in enumerate(sorted(self.data.keys())):
            horHeaders.append(key)
            for m, item in enumerate(self.data[key]):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                self.setItem(m, n, newitem)
                colorVal = "Qt.%s" % item
                self.item(m, n).setBackground(eval(colorVal))
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)

def main(args):
    app = QApplication(args)
    table = MyTable(data, 3, 1)
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Looking through it I think you might have misunderstood my question. The code you posted looks like it sets the cell background to whatever is the cell value ("red") when what I'm after is to set selection background (which you kept constant in the css) as a blend of current cell background. I admit I didn't understand your code completely (I'm using qt5) so feel free to correct me!